# Problems trying to get php foreach working

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I am trying to do the following... select all columns from the table `hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addemailtemplate`, then echo the data from each record, from the columns emailformname and emailformmessage. I am using the following code but am getting a bunch of errors, I am just learning php so it is probably a bit wrong :-S .

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addemailtemplate") or die(mysql_error());
    foreach($query as $detail) {
        echo $emailarray->emailformname;
        echo $emailarray->emailformmessage;
    }
?>
```

Comment: If you're just learning, you should really be learning [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), not the age old `mysql_` extension.

Comment: No, I think that's better first learn how the basic stuff works, then pass to the serious stuff such as PDO.. Starting from a DBAL with no knowledge on what's going on underneath it isn't a good idea, imho

Comment: PDO is just as transparent as the mysql_ extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, it is probably better to learn PDO for those just learning. It is more secure, more information and a tutorial can be found here:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

If you want to use objects with a mysql query, something like this will allow you to do so:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("hostname", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("mydb");
$result = mysql_query("select * from mytable");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo $row->user_id;
    echo $row->fullname;
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php

If you would like to do what Frits mentioned, then something like this will achieve your result:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

There is also arrays as an alternative:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: thanks for your help, this worked in the end after following your example :

<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addemailtemplate");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo $row->emailformname;
    echo $row->emailformmessage;
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>

I didnt need the db connect stuff as its inside of joomla im playing with stuff.

Thanks for everyone elses help, today I bought a big book on php and mysql so will be reading that and will hopefully be less crappy soon :-) .

Answer (score 1):

Oh this just make me smile :)

Look at the code samples on: http://php.net/mysql_query

Use a `while` loop with `mysql_fetch_assoc` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addemailtemplate";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo $row['emailformname']; // emailformname is a col name
     echo $row['emailformmessage']; // emailformmessage is a col name
}
```

Comment: When I put this into dreamweaver, it is flagging an error on this line   $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
im not sure why though ?

Comment: Sorry was typing to fast, missing semi colon at the end of the first line.

Comment: ah ok, thanks for your help, I will keep that one in my snippets folder of examples too now its working :-)